# How to add class by jQuery after AJAX success without changing the existing AJAX code?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class abc by jQuery inside a input field which is coming after AJAX success. But I don't have permission to change any code in AJAX.

Comment: Can you share the code? and Why can't you change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). When your ajax is completed call $.when and send your ajax url in parameter :

```
$.when( $.ajax( "your_url.php" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  alert( 'my ajax is done I can change the input class name here' );
});
```

And if you want to change the input class name you can do this inside the function :

```
$('#myInputID').addClass('myNewClass');
```

Comment: approach is fine, but you dont need `$.when` to track the `ajax` request, since you have only one `ajax` request.  instead you can operate on the `jqXHR` object returned from `$.ajax`, which contains all the promise methods on it.eg. `.then`, `.done`

Comment: Yes true dreamweiver. But when he said `I dont have permission to change any code in AJAX` I thought to separate the code.

Comment: yes you dont have to change ajax code, just call `then` over the return object of  `$.ajax`. check the approach in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion...but my problem is very clear i dont have permission to change anything in ajax code so how should i do???

Comment: I know... You don't have to change your ajax to do that. Keep your ajax and just add this code in your javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` returns `jqXHR` object returns the Promise object, which could be used to track success/fail callback.

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise - [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHRhttp://)

**JS Code:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
}).
then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
       //process when ajax succeeds
    }, 
    function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
       //process when ajax fails
});
```